# When were trivialis and quadrivialis introduced?

Tags: vocabulary, medieval-latin, new-latin, word-comparison, adjective

The seven liberal arts were divided into *trivium* and *quadrivium*.
The easier half, *trivium*, gives rise to the adjective *trivialis*, which has connotations of simplicity and vulgarity.
The adjective *quadrivialis* serves — in addition to referring to *quadrivium* — as an antonym to *trivialis* (or so I understood).
The Latin word *quadrivialis* seems very rare, and so does the English counterpart "quadrivial".

When were these two adjectives, *trivialis* and *quadrivialis* introduced to Latin?
Were they always opposite to each other (one meaning simple and the other meaning advanced), or did this contrast develop later?
Was there a different established antonym for *trivialis* if *quadrivialis* was much rarer than *trivialis*?
I would like to see these two adjectives and their histories compared.
If a full account is available but too long to share here, I would much appreciate an outline and a link to further reading.

Searching for *quadrivialis* does produce some hits, but I was unable to track any discussion to reliable or more complete sources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the cursory etymology you stated is inaccurate. Here is what my research shows:

### Medieval Latin meaning of *trivium / trivialis*

In the Middle Ages, the liberal arts were divided into the *trivium* (grammar, logic, and rhetoric) and the *quadrivium* (music, arithmetic, geometry and astronomy), but this was hardly a relationship of easy and difficult.

The *quadrivium* ("four ways") was first [coined by Boethius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrivium) in the 6th century. *trivium* as a term for the other three liberal arts was later coined in imitation of this term [during the Carolingian Renaissance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium). In this sense, they refer to the "three/four ways of knowledge."

According to the [Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=trivial), the first use of English *trivial* is in the early 15th century to mean "of the first three liberal arts," corresponding to the Medieval Latin *trivialis* which had the same meeting. At this point, it had no dismissive undertones.

### Post-Augustinian meaning of *trivium / trivialis*

The current meaning of *trivial* ("straightforward, unimportant") comes from the (post-Augustinian, but certainly not medieval) Latin word [*trivialis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtrivialis), which Lewis & Short translates as "that may be found everywhere, common, commonplace, vulgar, ordinary, trivial." This in turn is an adjective coming from [*trivium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtrivium), "a place where three roads meet" (*tres* + *via*) and, by extension, "a public square, the public street, highway."

The Online Etymological Dictionary (*op. cit.*) indicates that **this prior meaning is the origin of the current meaning of *trivial*, not the later Medieval Latin coining to refer to the three humane liberal arts.**

We thus have a case of two separate derived meanings coming from the same word, *trivium*, which literally means "the meeting of three ways."

This is the explanation for why *quadrivial* is not a common word in English and certainly is not an antonym of *trivial*: *quadrivial* is an adjective referring to the *quadrivium* or, literally, referring to the meeting of four ways, but there is no non-Medieval Latin word *quadrivialis* which had an extended meaning like *trivialis*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks! I added a little section at the end concerning *quadrivial*, since I forgot to address that.